# program using operator overloading produces garbage output

Tags: c++

The following code gives garbage output(arbitrary integers values) .Also the overloaded << operator isn't working(when the cout in `vector operator+(vector&)` is removed). How can I correct it ?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class vector
{
    int num;
    int ele[20];
    public:
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&,vector&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,vector&);
    vector operator+(vector&);
};

istream& operator>>(istream& is,vector& v)
{
    is >> v.num;
    for(int i = 0;i < v.num; i++)
    {
        is >> v.ele[i];
    }
    return is;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,vector& v)
{
    for(int i = 0;i < v.num; i++)
    {
        os << v.ele[i] << endl;
    }
    return os;
}

vector vector::operator+(vector& v)
{
    vector v2;
    if(num == v.num)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i < v.num; i++)
        {
            v2.ele[i] = ele[i] + v.ele[i];
            cout << v2.ele[i] << endl;
        }
        return v2;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector v1,v2,v3;
    int i, j;
    cin>>v1;
    cin>>v2;
    cin>>i;
    cin>>j;
    v3 = v1+v2;
    cout<<v3;
}
```

Comment: "Also the overloaded << operator isn't working(when the cout in `vector operator+(vector&)` is removed)."[Couldn't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BTVFvXSb5Zs4dZGj).

Comment: It's working after setting v2.num = num as mentioned in your answer.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You failed to set value to `v2.num` in `vector vector::operator+(vector& v)`, so set it.

Also you should return something explicitly on *every* control path of non-void funtion.

```
vector vector::operator+(vector& v)
{
    vector v2;
    if(num == v.num)
    {
        v2.num = num; // add this
        for(int i = 0;i < v.num; i++)
        {
            v2.ele[i] = ele[i] + v.ele[i];
            cout << v2.ele[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    else // add this section
    {
        v2.num = 0;
    }
    return v2; // move this
}
```